# Issues implementing YouTube API to app - Build errors using gtm-oauth2

Tags: ios, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-objc-client

Following an answer from a previous question [Setting up YouTube access within app, stuck on retrieving url response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929180/setting-up-youtube-access-within-app-stuck-on-retrieving-url-response) I have added GTM-OAuth2 files from [Google Toolbox for mac](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/) in order to use the YouTube API,  I imported the following files (as per instructed by Googletoolbox)

- GTMOAuth2Authentication.h/m
- GTMOAuth2SignIn.h/m
- GTMHTTPFetcher.h/m
- GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h/m
- GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.XIB

The GTMHTTPFetcher.h/m files were not in the Google Toolbox for Mac link, though I searched on Google and found both .h/m files elsewhere.

I disabled the ARC for these files (as instructed) and put -obj to Other Linker Flags.

When I Build & Run, I get a build error saying

```
Property 'delegateQueue' not found on object of type 'id<GTMHTTPFetcherServiceProtocol>'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I've not seen this error posted anywhere else?
Thanks in advance, Jim

Edit - For what it's worth, I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and set to deployment target 6.1
I tried changing to different deployment targets, sometimes this delegateQueue issue disappeared though when it did 13 more build errors came in stating other issues, mainly about syntax fix suggestions changing "**_blahCode** Did you mean **blahCode?** - Fix?" etc

Comment: Update- I re-imported the files finding the most recent files. The errors changed and with a lot of tweaking (mainly looking for more up to date .h/m files) I got the errors to go away. I now have an issue calling the OAuth2 viewController?

Comment: UPDATE - Managed to solve calling the viewController. Incase anyone else has same problem relating to code [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];, I changed this to read [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil]; and it worked. Still not out of woods as more problems after this, but that may be for another question.